# ifdown <interface> reports unknown interface when it exists!

Tags: networking

Running 16.04 w/ USB ethernet running `ifconfig -a` lists the interface named as `enx00051ba6daff` however when I try to bring that interface down with:

```
sudo ifdown enx00051ba6daff
```

I get:

```
Unknown interface enx00051ba6daff
```

I know its up because I'm writing this post from this connection.  My ifconfig is as follows:

```
enx00051ba6daff Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  
          inet addr:192.168.2.105  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:86522 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:84828 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:56466348 (56.4 MB)  TX bytes:12987882 (12.9 MB)
```

Comment: Could you please add the output of `ifconfig enx00051ba6daff` ?

Comment: or the output of `ifconfig` Ive never seen a device listing like that.

Comment: It's a USB gigE + 3 x USB3 ports.  Again, the Eth interface works, it just doesn't like the name when used with ifdown/ifup but I realized I can do it with ifconfig <interface> down/up but that doesn't allow me to change vlans without reboot.

Answer (score 29):

Try

```
sudo ifconfig enx00051ba6daff down
```

I had the exact same problem and this worked. Here is the link I used. 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1323646

Comment: For people who don't have `ifconfig` anymore try `ip link set enx00051ba6daff down`

Answer (score 9):

`sudo ifdown enx00051ba6daff` or `sudo ifup enx00051ba6daff`, will not work because enx00051ba6daff is not explicitly defined inside `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

So `ifup | ifdown | ifquery` family of functions is pretty unaware of what is inside the system unless this is written inside `/etc/network/interfaces`, but they could be since they all depend internally on `ip`¹ command.

It is more secure to use the `sudo ifconfig enx00051ba6daff down` or `sudo ifconfig enx00051ba6daff up`.

Note: There are couple things `sudo ifconfig enx00051ba6daff down` or `sudo ifconfig enx00051ba6daff up` will not do comparing to `sudo ifdown enx00051ba6daff` and `sudo ifup enx00051ba6daff`. `ifup` and `ifdown` will keep the state of interfaces inside `/run/network/ifstate` so `ifstate` command can tell you the state of the interface. And one another thing, if you `ifup` or `ifdown` the interface, the scripts inside `/etc/network/if-*.d` will run (`if-down.d  if-post-down.d  if-pre-up.d  if-up.d`)

¹<sub>ip link show, will show you the correct interfaces just as ifconfig will.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The commands `ifdown` and `ifup` listen to the file `/etc/network/interfaces`. In your case, it cannot find the interfaces, because they are not defined within this file.

You can fix this by:

1. Use the command

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
   ```

   or vi instead of nano, if you prefer.
2. Here you can add an entry like this:

   ```
   auto enx00051ba6daff
   iface enx00051ba6daff inet dhcp
   ```
3. Now you must restart your network services for the change to take effect. You can do so by running one of the following commands

   ```
   systemctl restart networking.service
   ```

   or

   ```
   /etc/init.d/networking restart
   ```

I know this response is well over-due, but I'm contributing this as a reference for others.
Hope this helps!

Comment: On ubuntu 22 desktop, this worked for me as a solution.
Strange that `service networking restart` did not work, while `ifdown enp2s0 && ifup enp2s0` did.

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

Go to `/etc/network/interfaces.d/`

I didn't found the setup file.

i created one

```
nano /etc/network/interfaces.d/setup
```

with below contents:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlp2s0
iface wlp2s0 inet dhcp
```

Then restart the service.

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Then try ifdown:

```
ifdown wlp2s0
```

It worked!!!