# IPv4 address from ifconfig differs from dhclient

Tags: networking, dhcp

After replacing the DHCP server (new router) I experience a weird situation on my ubuntu server (20.04.2 LTS)

ifconfig says (old):

```
enp0s31f6: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.2.165  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
```

dhclient says (new):

```
DHCPACK of 192.168.10.21 from 192.168.10.1 (xid=0xcad5f460)
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
bound to 192.168.10.21 -- renewal in 1080455 seconds.
```

I can ping both addresses and get an answer.

`dhclient -r` renews the 10.21-address, but does not touch the 2.165 address
`systemctl restart network-manager` did not resolve the issue

Some vdr-services use the old address and gets denied. Restarting vdr did not resolve the issue.

Can I resolve this without a reboot?

Comment: Was 192.168.2.165 what you were assigned by your old DHCP router? Or did you add that as a static IP to your system? The problem of access denied is a wrong route. You'd need to fix the gateway so it goes to the new address (10.21).

Comment: That was the old dhcp address. I wonder why this stil persists..

Answer (score 0):

I would look at deleting the old lease file:

```
/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases
```

Then run the `dhclient -r` to re-assign the `192.168.10.21` IP address. You may also specify the network interface:

```
dhclient -r -v enp0s31f6
```

Also, once you deleted the file and removed the IP, you may want to quickly send a request to get the new IP:

```
dhclient -v enp0s31f6
```

The problem with DHCP is that it views IP addresses on a different network as possibly coming from a different DHCP. So when your DHCP client queries the server with the old address, it *thinks* it was assigned by a different server and it ignores all such requests instead of telling the client to delete that old IP address.

Your network mask is `255.255.255.0` which means that `192.168.2.x` and `192.168.10.x` are two different networks.

As a side note: you can assign many IP addresses to the same network card. (In the old days, it was as many as 65534 or so). So it is normal to see two or more addresses on the same card. It is especially used to assign an IPv4 and an IPv6 set of addresses to a card.

Comment: The file you mentioned only contains the new ipv4 address. Deleting and renewing did not change the answer from ifconfig

Comment: Just in case, have you tried `sudo ifdown enp0s31f6` and then `sudo ifup enp0s31f6` to see what happens?

Comment: I was afraid you proposed that since it's a bit risky on a machine thats physically farther away, but the system reaction is comedy gold: ifdown: unknown interface enp0s31f6

Comment: Maybe see [ifdown: unknown interface](https://askubuntu.com/questions/870447/ifdown-interface-reports-unknown-interface-when-it-exists). Note that if you are trying that remotely, you can run both commands on the same line, just by a `;` in between the two. That way it will restart automatically. Hopefully, you still have physical access, somehow (just in case...)

Comment: Some people also mention `/etc/init.d/networking restart`, which may be even safer. I've never used that, but it could properly reset everything and then you get a new DHCP lease and a valid route...

Comment: Thanks for your hints. `/etc/init.d/networking restart ` did work but not change the ifconfig output. I'm not sure we're operating on the "old" way of network interface and the "new"  world run by systemd does not take notice

Comment: Ok, I risked the reboot I wanted to avoid. `ifconfig` now show the new address but `vdradmin` is still trying to talk to the old address although I reconfigured it - but that's a different problem.

Comment: I have had problems with `ifconfig` where some IP addresses would stick. Now I use `netplan` (which I assume is systemd) and that works way better.

Comment: Thanks, checked the man page...that looks like a longer reading session... :-)